# Order results based on count using spring boot specification API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, specifications

Consider the entity below.

**PS: The model has more fields but for the question to be short I have posted only the relevant fields**

```
Class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String region;
    private String department

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Skill> skills;
}


Class Skill {
    private name;
}
```

I am using spring boot Specification API to filter employees on different fields like region, country, and so on.

```
public class EmployeeSpec implements Specification<Employee> {
    
@Override
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Employee> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

    String fielName = //some field name
    String fieldValue = //some field value

    switch (fielName ) {
      case "country":
        return cb.equal(root.get("country"), fieldValue);
      case "department":
        return cb.equal(root.get("department"), fieldValue);
      case "region":
        return cb.equal(root.get("region"), fieldValue);
    }
}
```

I want to order the results such that employee with maximum skills comes first. I am not sure how to implement this using Specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CriteriaBuilder.size(..)`. For your case, the code will look like:

```
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.size(root.get("skills"))));
```